How can I increase the PWM frequency in this LTC7004 high side driver circuit?

I've been working on a high side driver circuit based around the LTC7004.  The use case is for driving generic loads on a boat (LED lights, motors, pumps, fans, other electronics, etc.)  In my latest iteration of the design, I was testing with a 12V white LED strip which has a forward voltage drop of ~8V.  I was having major issues using PWM to control the brightness.
I'm pretty sure the problem was that the voltage on the source pins of the MOSFET would only drop to ~8V when the MOSFET was turned off. If the source voltage was too high at the start of the next on cycle, the LTC7004 would start acting erratic and not recover. Luckily, the source would slowly drain to 0V through the voltage sense voltage divider, and I could operate at a very low PWM frequency.  I changed the voltage divider to be ~5k ohms total, and that has allowed me to run at ~300Hz.  That solution is not ideal, since the voltage divider then uses more power at 24V than I would like.  I would also like to have the option to run at higher frequencies to avoid flickering.
The fix that I came up with is to add an SN74 series inverter connected to the PWM signal and a small MOSFET to "drain" the charge from the source of the power MOSFET when it is turned off.  So far, this is working great.  I'm easily driving it at 10kHz+. I'm using a low value resistor (10R) and if the MOSFET somehow gets latched into the on state when the main power resistor is on, it will definitely fry that resistor or the small MOSFET instantly.  If I use a larger resistor that would be fine at 30V (my maximum design voltage) then the switching speed goes way down.
My question is if there are any potential issues with this, or if there is a better way to achieve this?

The discharge MOSFET has a very low resistance (10Ω), as you pointed out, there's a risk of damaging this MOSFET or the resistor if there's any failure or unintended prolonged ON state in the main power MOSFET. You can add a fast-acting fuse in series with the 10Ω resistor or discharge MOSFET could help protect the circuit in case of a failure.
